# How to maximize the use of the number 0 to optimize a program

Tags: c++, optimization, cpu, hardware

I was listening to a lecture at a C++ convention and speaker said to prefer zero above all other constants:

> "Zero is special because a bunch of operations within the machine
>   language of any CPU architecture have zero built in them."

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ea5DiCg8HOY)

Can someone here give me a concrete example of exploiting the integral 0 to make a program faster? I'm interested in starting to do this in programs that I write.

Sincerely, 
Mike Rowe Optimeiser

Comment: It does not matter today. The optimizing compiler would do better than you can.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Then why was the guy bringing it up in a conference last year?

Comment: When I click on the linked video, the first recommended video on the right is, by the same author, [Don't help the compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4).

Comment: All other things equal, a cache miss costs *much* more than using a >0 vs >1 test; the time to fetch data from RAM modules on full cache misses could be several hundreds cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic example, back many years ago when it mattered, was to count down from N to 0 rather than count up from 0 to N in cases where the direction didn't matter to the program logic. This could even exploit a "decrement and jump if not zero" instruction if your CPU had one which would be more efficient than an increment, a compare, and a conditional branch.

Comment: Intel out-of-order x86 implementations have for some time recognized and handled explicit zeroing outside of the main execution units. This avoids the use of a rename register (the register alias table instead points to the common zero value) and the use of execution functionality (including instruction scheduling and register file write ports).